# How to force select of a specific jquery-ui tab index or force 'tabsselect' event on specific tab?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have the following function:

```
function createTabs( selectorText, selected ) {
    var tabs = $( selectorText ).tabs();        
    if( selectorText == '#content .tabs' ) {
        contentTabs = tabs;
        $( selectorText ).unbind( 'tabsselect' ).bind( 'tabsselect', function( event, ui ) {            
            var queryNumber = $( ui.tab ).data('query_number');
            if( queryNumber ) {
                $( ui.panel ).html( '<table id="table"></table>' )
                var table = $( ui.panel ).find( 'table' );
                populateFlexigrid( table, queryNumber );
            }
        });
    }

    if( !selected ) {
        selected = 0;
        tabs.tabs( 'select', 0 )
    }
    tabs.tabs( 'select', selected );
}
```

In the `if` statement at the end of the function I am setting the selected tab to whatever tab should be selected.  When entering into this `if` statement the tab that is selected is always 0 because the tabs have just been created.  So my problem is that I'm trying to select a tab that is already selected.  This means the function I bound to that tab isn't executing.

**Is there any way I can force the tab to be selected or for the `tabsselect` event on that tab so my bound function runs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like [this solution](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/tabsselect-tabsshow-dont-fire-when-re-selecting-current-tab), but it is working.  If anyone has a better way please post it.

```
var selectedTab = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
$tabs.find('li').eq(selectedTab).removeClass('ui-tabs-selected').end().tabs('select', selectedTab);
```

Comment: Hey, sorry about the vote to your question earlier. It's not meant to be offensive. Just thought it would steer you in the right direction. Have a +1.

Comment: @JoeTuskan Haha, you are a scholar and a gentleman! I care too much about points (and I don't have many)... so downvotes hurt.  You did steer me in the right direction though. I did look through the related questions before I posted, I just missed that one some how :(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `tabs.trigger('tabsselect');` after selecting the tab.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry about the delay on this, but I finally found some time to work on this.

Try re-writing the "tabsselect" function as a named function (not anonymous), that way you can call it anytime you want to use it (after constructing the `ui` parameter that the event provides). Example code below (and [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aQvRg/)):

```
function tabSelected(event, ui) {
    var queryNumber = $(ui.tab).data('query_number');
    var table = $(ui.panel).find('table');
    console.log('Tab ' + ui.index + ' "tabsselect" event triggered.');
    if (queryNumber) {
        $(ui.panel).html('<table id="table"></table>');
        populateFlexigrid(table, queryNumber);
    }
}

function createTabs(selectorText, selected) {
    var tabs = $(selectorText).tabs();
    var tab = null;
    var panel = null;
    var ui = {
        "index": 0,
        "panel": tab,
        "tab": panel
    };

    if (selectorText == '#content .tabs') {
        contentTabs = tabs;
        $(selectorText).unbind('tabsselect').bind('tabsselect', tabSelected);
    }

    if (!selected) {
        selected = 0;
        tabs.tabs('select', 0);
    }

    //create the ui parameter
    ui.index = selected;
    ui.tab = $(tabs.children('ul:first').children('li')[selected]).children('a')[0];
    ui.panel = tabs.children('div')[selected];

    //run the "tabsselect" function
    tabSelected(null, ui);
}
createTabs('#content .tabs', 0);​
```